# How to check for internal damage after a fall?

Tags: mac

Without taking the mac apart since I tend to break things easily. Wasn't a really huge fall about 2-4 feet. Landed upside down and no visible damage.

Comment: What year and model is your mac? You can find this under the , and clicking 'About this Mac'. I just want the type and year to walk you through the Hardware Diagnostics and Testing.

Comment: 13 inch mid 2012 Mac Book Air

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mac is running the most El Capitan (OS X 10.11.x), and was made after 2012, you can perform the Apple Hardware Test (instructions see Method 1). If the mac was made before 2012, or is not running OS X 10.8.4 or above, you will have to follow the second set of instructions I will include in this guide.

---

Method 1

1. Disconnect all cables, with exception to the power adapter (which is required to continue), keyboard, mouse, Ethernet cable, and display.
2. Power off your computer, then power it on using the power button located on the computer.
3. Press the 'D' key on the computer while starting up, but before the grey screen appears.
4. Wait for a minute or two, and select your language.
5. To perform a quick check, you may press the t button, or return.
6. To perform a thorough check, you must select "perform extended testing".
7. The status of the check will appear in the bottom right of the screen.

Method 2

1. See step one through step 3 in method 1.
2. Follow onscreen instructions.

Sources:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18765

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201257

Comment: Dunno why but it feels like the mac seems to perform better now compared to before

Comment: The hardware test likely cleared the RAM caches and reset the PRAM.

Comment: I understand this is off topic, but for improved performance, clear the PRAM before a boot, see this Apple support article. https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204063